# Insert record in table

Tags: sql, sh

Using shell script i am trying to execute sql database like as

```
for file in `ls -lrt *.rules | awk '{print $9}'`
do
while IFS='|' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4
do
awk -F "|" '{print "UPDATE ETPRO_UPDATE SET IS_ACTIVE = 0 WHERE ID="$1";"}' $file && break
awk -F "|"  '{print "insert into ETPRO_UPDATE (ID,NAME) values("$1",'"'"'"$2"'"'"');"}' $file && break
done < "$file"
done | sqlplus -s $SQLUSER/$SQLPASS@ora12c
```

In above Script

1. first i am updating the is_active column to zero which is set as by default 1.
2. then inserting the same record to the table,which will have is_active value 1 as per requirement(not worry about duplicate).

   but i am not able to insert complete data properly(some data got miss or only one query is getting executed.)

Comment: I would suspect you are `break`ing before your really want to...

Comment: yes but if i didn't use break then it keep on adding all changes in one file...